# Auto-Generate Longtail-SEO Pages/URLs

Tags: templates, seo

## Situation:

I read [this article](https://marketingexamples.com/seo/dominate-long-tail-keywords) on how nomadlist.com uses its crowdsourced data to automatically create individual pages to be visibile for longtail seo-keywords. The author states that they use a php-template, but I'm not sure what he bases that statement on.

Our project collects crowdsourced data and I'm struggling a bit to replicate this.
 Especially since I don't have any control over the number of data-points to build pages from.

**Example:**
One example would be written travel-experiences for any location in newzealand.
In this example we collect a location, a mood and a written text whenever a user posts something.

**User A:** Location(City): Auckland, Mood: Happy, Text: "..."
**User B:** Location(City): Wellington, Mood: Sad, Text: "..."
**User C:** Location(City): Christchurch, Mood: Angry, Text: "..."

The "Location" is collected via [mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/) api and then saved to our database.

The "Mood" is collected via radio-buttons and has a known number of predefined choices.

## Questions:

**1. How can I generate pages/urls with titles like: "10 (Happy) Experiences from (Auckland)"?**
I dont know how to achieve this technically and am specifically struggling with the unknown number of possible locations and the page should only be available if we actually have a minimum of 10 (Happy) entries for (Auckland).

**2. How can I make searchengines recognize these "pages" if they are not "physically" created, but only made available via urls?**

Any push in the right direction is appreciated, since I'm completely new to these kind of generated content pages.
Thanks!

---

### Addition 1 - How the system captures data:

Data is captured via a chatbot created with [botman](https://botman.io/).

A user can trigger the creation of a new entry via a typed command. The chatbot then asks 5 questions (e.g. mood and location) and writes the users answers to the database when the final question in the sequence has been answered.

### Addition 2 - How the system stores data:

An entry is saved as a custom post type in the wp_posts table. So main fields like post ID, date, post image and content come from there.

Additional information is saved to the wp_postmeta table with the following fields: Meta_ID, Post_ID, meta_key, meta_value. So things like mood, location or weather each have their own row in the wp_postmeta table and are assigned to an entry from there.

Comment: Can you provide more information on how your system captures the data and stores it? Is it within WordPress or by other means?

Comment: Hi @Tom, good thought. I've added this to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, likely if there are complete lists of options for "mood" and "location" than there could just be a script that generates all combination of them and - while generating - double check if there is actually enough content for them.

And then put them in the sitemap that google uses for getting to know the site?

In WordPress, in reality, every side is virtual / "not physical". 
The URL is parsed against the rewrite rules and a database query is built through that which pulls content, decides which template is to be used and puts it in there. 
But yeah - something like a post that has a "real thing" in the database is maybe more physical.

Also don't know how "virtual sides" work with caching. But maybe the sitemap is also a good thing for that.

I am not experienced in this, just trying to collect ideas.